# Выбор двух дат при условии не disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

`air datepicker` Не получается сделать условие, при котором нельзя будет выбирать `range`, когда между датами есть `disabled`. Кто знает, не стесняйтесь подсказывать ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var disabledDates = ['2018-5-24', '2018-5-25', '2018-5-26'];

    var $start = $('#start');
    var $end = $('#end');

    $start.datepicker({
        inline: false,
        range: true,
        toggleSelected: true,
        minDate: new Date(),
        multipleDatesSeparator: ",",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        onSelect: function (fd, date) {
            if(date){
                var arr = fd.split(",");
                $start.val(arr[0]);
                $end.val(arr[1]);
                if(arr[1]){
                    $('.datepicker').css("left", "-100000px");
                    $start.blur();
                }
                $end.on('click', function () {
                    $start.datepicker().val(arr[0]).data('datepicker').show();
                });
            }
        },
        onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
            var formatted = getFormattedDate(date);
            if (cellType == 'day') {
                var returnDay = {
                    disabled: false
                };
                var ab = disabledDates.filter(function(date){
                    return date == formatted;
                }).length;
                if( ab > 0){
                    returnDay = {
                        disabled: true
                    };
                }
                return returnDay;
            }
        }
    });
    
    function getFormattedDate(date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear(),
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            date = date.getDate();
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
    }
    
});
```

```css
.reservation-calendar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="reservation-calendar">
    <div class="reservation-calendar__item line">
        <input class="start" type="text" id="start">
    </div>
     - 
    <div class="reservation-calendar__item">
        <input class="start" type="text" id="end">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит один и тот же? чем это отличается от "такой же"

Comment: Я имел в виду, что открывается этот же календарь с уже внесенными изменениями. По клику на первый инпут выбрал 2 даты. По клику на второй инпут, появляется не новый календарь, а тот же, с выбранными датами

Comment: вряд ли вы привяжите два инпута прям к одному объекту календаря, но почему бы не пробрасывать выбранные даты во второй календарь?

Comment: Хотелось чтобы календарь был тот же, не мигал при переходе из одного календаря на другой

Comment: тогда при клике во второй инпут просто показывайте календарь в первом, а-ля `$start.datepicker().data('datepicker').show()`

Comment: а вы не знаете метод, с помощью которого можно было добавить массив дат, которые будут `disabled` ?

Comment: в [документации](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html) для отключения используется событие `onRenderCell`.  Большего чем там написано сказать не могу, ибо первый раз вижу этот плагин

Comment: Спасибо за ваше время, буду разбираться